# Cassandra NoHostAvailableException : All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

We are running a java micro service that uses Cassandra DB multi node cluster. While writing data seeing following error randomly from different nodes:

**com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed**

Already verified that all nodes are available and running and are reachable to each other in the cluster.

Any pointer are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified you're authenticated and have the correct permissions to perform your query? I just ran into this issue in DataGrip when trying to create a keyspace using the official Scylla container. Scylla is a Cassandra compatible column-store and its official container isn't supposed to have authentication enabled by default but when I tried to create a keyspace I ran into the OP's exception. When reviewing the container's log I noticed it creates a superuser named cassandra with the password of cassandra. When I used these credentials I was able to successfully create the keyspace.

Answer (score 0):

Above error suggests that driver was unable to connect to any of the host for a query. Following could be the reasons for the same.

1. Cassandra Node down - Which you have verified is not the case for you.
2. Congestion due to high traffic due to which nodes are shown down.
3. Intermittent issues in network connectivity between client and nodes which compels driver to mark the host down.

Comment: Thanks Manish. But we have verified the network issue, and traffic is also normal. All cassandra nodes in cluster is having ReleaseVersion: 3.9. And the Datastax Java driver version is 3.0, which is also compatible. What else can trigger this issue

Comment: Long GC pauses could be the reason. You can check your gc logs at the time when you are getting above error logs. If that is the reason you have to tune your C* nodes.

Comment: if we reduce the value for gc_grace_seconds from default to 0, will it help. I know that tombstones is major reason for higher GC activity in general. Another alternate is to filter out null values using Mapper options and set saveNullFields(false) . Please suggest is we can take some more steps.